# Problem seeing table from flextable package using rpy2

Tags: r, rpy2, flextable

I'm using R on Jupyter Lab through rpy2. So far it's worked fine for me, but when trying to use the flextable function from the flextable package, there is nothing when I use the function print.

```
%%R # -w 400 -h 100 -u mm -r 390 -p 1 --type cairo-png 

library('tidyverse') 
library('flextable')

ft <- flextable(head(mtcars))
print(ft, type = "html")
```

This result from the code above should be equal to the picture below.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fr9vD.png)

However, when I've been receiving a file with the content below on my computer and run it in any HTML compiler, it will look the same as the picture above.

------------ index.html ---------------

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<style>body{background-color:white;}</style>
<link href="lib/tabwid-1.1.3/tabwid.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="lib/tabwid-1.1.3/tabwid.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<style></style>
<div class="tabwid"><style>.cl-1c67ebe4{}.cl-1c4c1f54{font-family:'Arial';font-size:11pt;font-weight:normal;font-style:normal;text-decoration:none;color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 1.00);background-color:transparent;}.cl-1c57e014{margin:0;text-align:right;border-bottom: 0 solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 1.00);border-top: 0 solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 1.00);border-left: 0 solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 1.00);border-right: 0 solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 1.00);padding-bottom:5pt;padding-top:5pt;padding-left:5pt;padding-right:5pt;line-height: 1;background-color:transparent;}.cl-1c5830a0{width:0.75in;background-color:transparent;vertical-align: middle;border-bottom: 1.5pt solid rgba(102, 102, 102, 1.00);border-top: 1.5pt solid rgba(102, 102, 102, 1.00);border-left: 0 solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 1.00);border-right: 0 solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 1.00);margin-bottom:0;margin-top:0;margin-left:0;margin-right:0;}.cl-1c5830b4{width:0.75in;background-color:transparent;vertical-align: middle;border-bottom: 0 solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 1.00);border-top: 0 solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 1.00);border-left: 0 solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 1.00);border-right: 0 solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 1.00);margin-bottom:0;margin-top:0;margin-left:0;margin-right:0;}.cl-1c5830c8{width:0.75in;background-color:transparent;vertical-align: middle;border-bottom: 1.5pt solid rgba(102, 102, 102, 1.00);border-top: 0 solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 1.00);border-left: 0 solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 1.00);border-right: 0 solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 1.00);margin-bottom:0;margin-top:0;margin-left:0;margin-right:0;}</style><table data-quarto-disable-processing='true' class='cl-1c67ebe4'><thead><tr style="overflow-wrap:break-word;"><th class="cl-1c5830a0"><p class="cl-1c57e014"><span class="cl-1c4c1f54">mpg</span></p></th><th class="cl-1c5830a0"><p class="cl-1c57e014"><span class="cl-1c4c1f54">cyl</span></p></th><th class="cl-1c5830a0"><p class="cl-1c57e014"><span class="cl-1c4c1f54">disp</span></p></th><th class="cl-1c5830a0"><p class="cl-1c57e014"><span class="cl-1c4c1f54">hp</span></p></th><th class="cl-1c5830a0"><p class="cl-1c57e014"><span class="cl-1c4c1f54">drat</span></p></th><th class="cl-1c5830a0"><p class="cl-1c57e014"><span class="cl-1c4c1f54">wt</span></p></th><th class="cl-1c5830a0"><p class="cl-1c57e014"><span class="cl-1c4c1f54">qsec</span></p></th><th class="cl-1c5830a0"><p class="cl-1c57e014"><span class="cl-1c4c1f54">vs</span></p></th><th class="cl-1c5830a0"><p class="cl-1c57e014"><span class="cl-1c4c1f54">am</span></p></th><th class="cl-1c5830a0"><p class="cl-1c57e014"><span class="cl-1c4c1f54">gear</span></p></th><th class="cl-1c5830a0"><p class="cl-1c57e014"><span class="cl-1c4c1f54">carb</span></p></th></tr></thead><tbody><tr style="overflow-wrap:break-word;"><td class="cl-1c5830b4"><p class="cl-1c57e014"><span class="cl-1c4c1f54">21.0</span></p></td><td class="cl-1c5830b4"><p class="cl-1c57e014"><span class="cl-1c4c1f54">6</span></p></td><td class="cl-1c5830b4"><p class="cl-1c57e014"><span class="cl-1c4c1f54">160</span></p></td><td class="cl-1c5830b4"><p class="cl-1c57e014"><span class="cl-1c4c1f54">110</span></p></td><td class="cl-1c5830b4"><p class="cl-1c57e014"><span class="cl-1c4c1f54">3.90</span></p></td><td class="cl-1c5830b4"><p class="cl-1c57e014"><span class="cl-1c4c1f54">2.620</span></p></td><td class="cl-1c5830b4"><p class="cl-1c57e014"><span class="cl-1c4c1f54">16.46</span></p></td><td class="cl-1c5830b4"><p class="cl-1c57e014"><span class="cl-1c4c1f54">0</span></p></td><td class="cl-1c5830b4"><p class="cl-1c57e014"><span class="cl-1c4c1f54">1</span></p></td><td class="cl-1c5830b4"><p class="cl-1c57e014"><span class="cl-1c4c1f54">4</span></p></td><td class="cl-1c5830b4"><p class="cl-1c57e014"><span class="cl-1c4c1f54">4</span></p></td></tr><tr style="overflow-wrap:break-word;"><td class="cl-1c5830b4"><p class="cl-1c57e014"><span class="cl-1c4c1f54">21.0</span></p></td><td class="cl-1c5830b4"><p class="cl-1c57e014"><span class="cl-1c4c1f54">6</span></p></td><td class="cl-1c5830b4"><p class="cl-1c57e014"><span class="cl-1c4c1f54">160</span></p></td><td class="cl-1c5830b4"><p class="cl-1c57e014"><span class="cl-1c4c1f54">110</span></p></td><td class="cl-1c5830b4"><p class="cl-1c57e014"><span class="cl-1c4c1f54">3.90</span></p></td><td class="cl-1c5830b4"><p class="cl-1c57e014"><span class="cl-1c4c1f54">2.875</span></p></td><td class="cl-1c5830b4"><p class="cl-1c57e014"><span class="cl-1c4c1f54">17.02</span></p></td><td class="cl-1c5830b4"><p class="cl-1c57e014"><span class="cl-1c4c1f54">0</span></p></td><td class="cl-1c5830b4"><p class="cl-1c57e014"><span class="cl-1c4c1f54">1</span></p></td><td class="cl-1c5830b4"><p class="cl-1c57e014"><span class="cl-1c4c1f54">4</span></p></td><td class="cl-1c5830b4"><p class="cl-1c57e014"><span class="cl-1c4c1f54">4</span></p></td></tr><tr style="overflow-wrap:break-word;"><td class="cl-1c5830b4"><p class="cl-1c57e014"><span class="cl-1c4c1f54">22.8</span></p></td><td class="cl-1c5830b4"><p class="cl-1c57e014"><span class="cl-1c4c1f54">4</span></p></td><td class="cl-1c5830b4"><p class="cl-1c57e014"><span class="cl-1c4c1f54">108</span></p></td><td class="cl-1c5830b4"><p class="cl-1c57e014"><span class="cl-1c4c1f54">93</span></p></td><td class="cl-1c5830b4"><p class="cl-1c57e014"><span class="cl-1c4c1f54">3.85</span></p></td><td class="cl-1c5830b4"><p class="cl-1c57e014"><span class="cl-1c4c1f54">2.320</span></p></td><td class="cl-1c5830b4"><p class="cl-1c57e014"><span class="cl-1c4c1f54">18.61</span></p></td><td class="cl-1c5830b4"><p class="cl-1c57e014"><span class="cl-1c4c1f54">1</span></p></td><td class="cl-1c5830b4"><p class="cl-1c57e014"><span class="cl-1c4c1f54">1</span></p></td><td class="cl-1c5830b4"><p class="cl-1c57e014"><span class="cl-1c4c1f54">4</span></p></td><td class="cl-1c5830b4"><p class="cl-1c57e014"><span class="cl-1c4c1f54">1</span></p></td></tr><tr style="overflow-wrap:break-word;"><td class="cl-1c5830b4"><p class="cl-1c57e014"><span class="cl-1c4c1f54">21.4</span></p></td><td class="cl-1c5830b4"><p class="cl-1c57e014"><span class="cl-1c4c1f54">6</span></p></td><td class="cl-1c5830b4"><p class="cl-1c57e014"><span class="cl-1c4c1f54">258</span></p></td><td class="cl-1c5830b4"><p class="cl-1c57e014"><span class="cl-1c4c1f54">110</span></p></td><td class="cl-1c5830b4"><p class="cl-1c57e014"><span class="cl-1c4c1f54">3.08</span></p></td><td class="cl-1c5830b4"><p class="cl-1c57e014"><span class="cl-1c4c1f54">3.215</span></p></td><td class="cl-1c5830b4"><p class="cl-1c57e014"><span class="cl-1c4c1f54">19.44</span></p></td><td class="cl-1c5830b4"><p class="cl-1c57e014"><span class="cl-1c4c1f54">1</span></p></td><td class="cl-1c5830b4"><p class="cl-1c57e014"><span class="cl-1c4c1f54">0</span></p></td><td class="cl-1c5830b4"><p class="cl-1c57e014"><span class="cl-1c4c1f54">3</span></p></td><td class="cl-1c5830b4"><p class="cl-1c57e014"><span class="cl-1c4c1f54">1</span></p></td></tr><tr style="overflow-wrap:break-word;"><td class="cl-1c5830b4"><p class="cl-1c57e014"><span class="cl-1c4c1f54">18.7</span></p></td><td class="cl-1c5830b4"><p class="cl-1c57e014"><span class="cl-1c4c1f54">8</span></p></td><td class="cl-1c5830b4"><p class="cl-1c57e014"><span class="cl-1c4c1f54">360</span></p></td><td class="cl-1c5830b4"><p class="cl-1c57e014"><span class="cl-1c4c1f54">175</span></p></td><td class="cl-1c5830b4"><p class="cl-1c57e014"><span class="cl-1c4c1f54">3.15</span></p></td><td class="cl-1c5830b4"><p class="cl-1c57e014"><span class="cl-1c4c1f54">3.440</span></p></td><td class="cl-1c5830b4"><p class="cl-1c57e014"><span class="cl-1c4c1f54">17.02</span></p></td><td class="cl-1c5830b4"><p class="cl-1c57e014"><span class="cl-1c4c1f54">0</span></p></td><td class="cl-1c5830b4"><p class="cl-1c57e014"><span class="cl-1c4c1f54">0</span></p></td><td class="cl-1c5830b4"><p class="cl-1c57e014"><span class="cl-1c4c1f54">3</span></p></td><td class="cl-1c5830b4"><p class="cl-1c57e014"><span class="cl-1c4c1f54">2</span></p></td></tr><tr style="overflow-wrap:break-word;"><td class="cl-1c5830c8"><p class="cl-1c57e014"><span class="cl-1c4c1f54">18.1</span></p></td><td class="cl-1c5830c8"><p class="cl-1c57e014"><span class="cl-1c4c1f54">6</span></p></td><td class="cl-1c5830c8"><p class="cl-1c57e014"><span class="cl-1c4c1f54">225</span></p></td><td class="cl-1c5830c8"><p class="cl-1c57e014"><span class="cl-1c4c1f54">105</span></p></td><td class="cl-1c5830c8"><p class="cl-1c57e014"><span class="cl-1c4c1f54">2.76</span></p></td><td class="cl-1c5830c8"><p class="cl-1c57e014"><span class="cl-1c4c1f54">3.460</span></p></td><td class="cl-1c5830c8"><p class="cl-1c57e014"><span class="cl-1c4c1f54">20.22</span></p></td><td class="cl-1c5830c8"><p class="cl-1c57e014"><span class="cl-1c4c1f54">1</span></p></td><td class="cl-1c5830c8"><p class="cl-1c57e014"><span class="cl-1c4c1f54">0</span></p></td><td class="cl-1c5830c8"><p class="cl-1c57e014"><span class="cl-1c4c1f54">3</span></p></td><td class="cl-1c5830c8"><p class="cl-1c57e014"><span class="cl-1c4c1f54">1</span></p></td></tr></tbody></table></div>
</body>
</html>
```

---

I believe the issue here is related to the HTML problem, it should be printed in my Jupyter instead of being output to a file like index.html. Perhaps I am not configuring that correctly when using rpy2.

Comment: Please remember that Stack Overflow is not your favourite R forum, but rather a question and answer site for all programming related questions. Thus, always include the tag of the language you are programming in, that way other users familiar with that language can more easily find your question. Take the [tour] and read up on [ask] to get more information on how this site works, then [edit] the question with the relevant tags.

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific about what the issue is? What do you mean by "can't see through the print"?

Comment: I tried to improve my question! thanks!

Comment: print is for interactive usage in R. If you are in a notebook, I think you have to NOT call print. But I am not sure if it will work, it has never been tested with Jupyter notebook, is that your case? (I think jupyterlab is the container where you launch a jupyter notebook, right??)

Comment: @DavidGohel I have made some attempts to improve my question based on my previous efforts. Regarding the print function, I have been working so far without any issues. However, in my opinion, the problem is cause I have not been capable to properly set up my environment correctly until now to HTML output.